# How to use the global variable to initialize the class property?

Tags: php, class, global-variables

I'm using PHP 7.2.6

I know that "A variable declared outside a function has a **GLOBAL SCOPE** and can only be accessed outside a function".

I want to the already declared global variable into my class.

I want to initialize the class property using this global variable.

For it, I tried below code

```
<?php
$str = <<<EOD
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using heredoc syntax.
EOD;

class foo
{
    var $foo;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->foo = $str;
    }
}

$foo = new foo();
echo $foo->foo;
?>
```

I got following notice in my browser :

```
Notice: Undefined variable: str in hello.php on line 14
```

I'm not understanding why I'm getting this notice.

I'm not accessing the global variable `$str` inside any function. I'm using it inside a class.

Please help me in this regard and also explain me how should I use the global variable to initialize the class property?

Comment: Are you aware, that since release of PHP 5.0 (that's 2004th-ish), the `var` keyword is not supposed to be used in class syntax? Also, why the hell are you not passing the value as a dependency in the constructor?

Comment: "A variable declared outside a function has a GLOBAL SCOPE and can only be accessed outside a function" - Not true.

Comment: @Progrock : This statement is by w3schools PHP tutorial URL : https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_variables.asp

Comment: Great that you provide a reference.  Poor choice of words.  As you can see, with the aid of the global keyword you can access variables in the global scope from within a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a global variable you need to use the global variable with `global` keyword, <strike>Secondly your modifier and class shares the same name which afaik will confuse the compiler see the below snippet</strike>

Nope It doesn't

```
   <?php

$str = <<<EOD
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using heredoc syntax.
EOD;

class foo
{
    public  $foo;

    function __construct()
    {
        global $str;
        $this->foo = $str;
    }


}

$foo = new foo();
echo $foo->foo;
?>
```

[Snippet](https://3v4l.org/VtmYo)

[Why not to use global variables](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad)